# Pass an unspecified set of parameters into a function and thru to a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Let's say I want to write a helper function that wraps `Read-Host`.  This function will enhance Read-Host by changing the prompt color, calling Read-Host, then changing the color back (simple example for illustrative purposes - not actually trying to solve for this).

Since this is a wrapper around Read-Host, I don't want to repeat the all of the parameters of Read-Host (i.e. Prompt and AsSecureString) in the function header.  Is there a way for a function to take an unspecified set of parameters and then pass those parameters directly into a cmdlet call within the function?  I'm not sure if Powershell has such a facility.

for example...

```
function MyFunc( [string] $MyFuncParam1, [int] $MyFuncParam2 , Some Thing Here For Cmdlet Params that I want to pass to Cmdlet )
{    
    # ...Do some work...
    Read-Host Passthru Parameters Here
    # ...Do some work...

}
```

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you're interested in the 'ValueFromRemainingArguments' parameter attribute. To use it, you'll need to create an advanced function. See the about_Functions_Advanced and about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters help topics for more info.

When you use that attribute, any extra unbound parameters will be assigned to that parameter. I don't think they're usable as-is, though, so I made a little function that will parse them (see below). After parsing them, two variables are returned: one for any unnamed, positional parameters, and one for named parameters. Those two variables can then be splatted to the command you want to run. Here's the helper function that can parse the parameters:

```
function ParseExtraParameters {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $ExtraParameters
    )

    $ParamHashTable = @{}
    $UnnamedParams = @()
    $CurrentParamName = $null
    $ExtraParameters | ForEach-Object -Process {
        if ($_ -match "^-") {
            # Parameter names start with '-'
            if ($CurrentParamName) {
                # Have a param name w/o a value; assume it's a switch
                # If a value had been found, $CurrentParamName would have
                # been nulled out again
                $ParamHashTable.$CurrentParamName = $true
            }

            $CurrentParamName = $_ -replace "^-|:$"
        }
        else {
            # Parameter value
            if ($CurrentParamName) {
                $ParamHashTable.$CurrentParamName += $_
                $CurrentParamName = $null
            }
            else {
                $UnnamedParams += $_
            }
        }
    } -End {
        if ($CurrentParamName) {
            $ParamHashTable.$CurrentParamName = $true
        }
    }

    ,$UnnamedParams
    $ParamHashTable
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
PS C:\> ParseExtraParameters -NamedParam1 1,2,3 -switchparam -switchparam2:$false UnnamedParam1

UnnamedParam1

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                 
switchparam                    True                                                                                                                                                  
switchparam2                   False                                                                                                                                                 
NamedParam1                    {1, 2, 3}
```

Here are two functions that can use the helper function (one is your example):

```
function MyFunc {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string] $MyFuncParam1, 
        [int] $MyFuncParam2,
        [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $ExtraParameters
    )
    # ...Do some work...
    $UnnamedParams, $NamedParams = ParseExtraParameters @ExtraParameters
    Read-Host @UnnamedParams @NamedParams
    # ...Do some work...
}

function Invoke-Something {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string] $CommandName,
        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $ExtraParameters
    )

    $UnnamedParameters, $NamedParameters = ParseExtraParameters @ExtraParameters
    &$CommandName @UnnamedParameters @NamedParameters
}
```

After importing all three functions, try these commands:

```
MyFunc -MyFuncParam1 Param1Here "PromptText" -assecure
Invoke-Something -CommandName Write-Host -Fore Green "Some text" -Back Red
```

Comment: woah!  seriously great answer, Rohn. Thank you for taking the time to write it up.  Should the call to Get-ParameterHashTable be ParseExtraParameters?  I'm curious if someone else knows of a way to use $ExtraParameters more directly (without the call to ParseExtractParameter).

Comment: If command (e.g. `Read-Host`) accepts positional parameters, than sure you can: `& { param ($a, $b, [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]$MyArgs) $c = Read-Host @MyArgs; "$a, $b, $c"} -a 1 -b 2 'this is prompt text' `

Answer (score 6):

One word: splatting.

Few more words: you can use combination of `$PSBoundParameters` and splatting to pass parameters from external command, to internal command (assuming names match). You would need to remove any parameter that you don't want to use though from `$PSBoundParameters` first:

```
$PSBoundParameters.Remove('MyFuncParam1')
$PSBoundParameters.Remove('MyFuncParam2')
Read-Host @PSBoundParameters
```

**EDIT**

Sample function body:

```
function Read-Data {
param (
    [string]$First,
    [string]$Second,
    [string]$Prompt,
    [switch]$AsSecureString
)

    $PSBoundParameters.Remove('First') | Out-Null
    $PSBoundParameters.Remove('Second') | Out-Null
    $Result = Read-Host @PSBoundParameters
    "First: $First Second: $Second Result: $Result"
}

Read-Data -First Test -Prompt This-is-my-prompt-for-read-host
```

Comment: Hi Bartek - thanks!  I'll need to read-up about splatting.  If it doesn't require too much time, could you provide an example function and how you would call it?

Comment: hi Bartek - In this solution you define Prompt and AsSecureString as parameters of Read-Data.  Per my question "I don't want to repeat the all of the parameters of Read-Host...in the function header".  I'm looking for some generic way to define a set of pass-thru parameters in a function.  For example, in the R-statistical language you can define a function MyFunc( x , y , ... ) { }  where the dot-dot-dot tells R to captures any other extra parameters you want to pass to MyFunc.  Inside MyFunc, you can pass the contents of dot-dot-dot into other functions.  Does PS have a similar feature?

Comment: Note that in my comment above, dot-dot-dot does not mean "and so on".  You literally you put three periods in the function header and then anything passed to MyFunc that isn't x or y is encapsulated in a datastructure that is created dynamically at run time.